# Powershell commands to get IP address

Tags: powershell

Is there any concept of primary IP and Backup IP in windows ? if it has then 
When I type ip config i get the below results.
Ethernet adapter PXE-Backup:

```
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe30::fc0t:386e:d899:16fb%1
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.229.69.109
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Ethernet adapter Production:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fl80::a196:9574:d9db:51f9%1
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.139.64.109
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.229.80.1
```

How to what is primary and backup ip ?..

Comment: `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:COMPUTERNAME).AddressList` or `gwmi win32_networkadapter | ? NetEnabled`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out **[`Get-NetIPConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipconfiguration?view=win10-ps)**!

For instance:

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration | Where-Object InterfaceAlias -eq "PXE-Backup"
```

Comment: This command does not work in windows 2008 R2 enterprise edition !

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Get-NetIPAddress` in the following ways:

```
Get-NetIPAddress
```

or

```
Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object -Property InterfaceAlias -Contains wifi
```

If you want to know your public IP Address then do this instead:

```
curl ifconfig.me
```

Alternatively for the last one you can visit the web page: https://ifconfig.me/